# Is it possible that I conduct a supervised machine learning like random forest after creating a target variable through clustering?

Tags: machine-learning

I create 4 clusters by using k-mean cluster analysis. After that, I try to classify this target variable with random forest in order to confirm if the clusters are properly grouped. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it is possible.
Somemore information would be helpful:
How do you plan to test/train? Do you want to use k-fold cross validation, or split the data? Are you going to use exactly the same variables as predictors in the Random Forest, that u used for the clusteranalysis? In this case you propably need to be careful with your interpretation since it is circular by nature.

Comment: I am going to use k-fold cross validation and use different predictors.

Comment: I think you need to consider the purpose of the analysis. What would be your research question / what is the primary aim? When you are using other predictors you could answer the question: is it possible to predict my new variable (4 categories identfied by CA)? Does such a finding validate the clusters you found? It's depended on your field of research and the existing theories within this field. You may also find this [link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_the_methods_we_can_use_to_validate_Clustering) helpful (Check the answer by Sambhavi Dhanabalan)